# How Can i check, if a Button is not clicked

Tags: javascript, onclick

I search a simple, short, and Pure Javascript method. I try to have a kind of this

```
 if (button.clicked === false) {
 }
```

a Answer with jsfiddle is good. But its not a must :D

Comment: `addEventListener('click', ....)`?

Comment: Clicked isn't a state, it's an event. A button is clicked when you click it, it's not clicked all the rest of the time. Maybe you want a checkbox?

Comment: such i add the listener to the button? And its the same like onclick. I search a "Notclick" or "outclick" function, with pure js. @Barmar

Comment: I think, he wants a solution to check if a button hasn't been clicked.

Comment: Make your `onclick` method set a global variable. Then you can check whether the variable is set.

Comment: I search a method if a person click. When he clicks on the button make function 1. Clicks out of the button, then make function 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Don't listen to anyone telling you to set a global variable** - you don't need it.

Every HTML Element is an object. We can simply define a separate property called `clicked`.

first we check if it's undefined. If it is we set it to `true`, otherwise we set it to the boolean opposite of whatever it's set to. This means if it was `true`, on click it becomes `false` and vice versa.

This property stays with the element. as demonstrated in the console log. I used `document.querySelector("button")` to go back out to the DOM in order to show that it is available from outside the click function.

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  (this.clicked != undefined) ?
  this.clicked = !this.clicked : 
  this.clicked = true;
  
  console.log(document.querySelector("button").clicked);
});
```

```html
<button>click me</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

Buttons don't remember whether they were clicked  automatically. You can add a `dataset` to the button to hold this information.

```js
var button1 = document.getElementById("button1");
button1.addEventListener("click", function() {
  button1.dataset.clicked = "true";
});

document.getElementById("button2").addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log(button1.dataset.clicked ? "Yes" : "No");
});
```

```html
<button id="button1">Click me</button>
<br>
<button id="button2">Was it clicked?</button>
```

Comment: I totaly agree with you , a click is an event not a state , a button is not clicked unless you click on it , it logic it not complicated

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to handle this is to play with `class` attribute to handle this.
for example:

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (this.classList.contains('not-yet-clicked')) {
    this.classList.remove('not-yet-clicked');
    this.textContent = 'The button is clicked';
    this.disabled = true;
  }
})
```

```html
<button class="not-yet-clicked">Click me</button>
```

Or if you want to play with flag, you do this:

```js
var clicked = false;
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function () {
  clicked = true;
  if (clicked) {
    this.textContent = 'Clicked';
    this.disabled = true;
  }
});
```

```html
<button>Not yet clicked</button>
```

Comment: When  you dont click the button, but clicks anywhere, then disable the button. Try this ;D

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't necessarily answer the question but it is related. I wanted to find a way for registering a click elsewhere, not knowing that you can add an event listener called 'focusout' instead of an event listener for a click other than that element.

If you have an input and want to know when someone clicks away from it:

```
input.addEventListener('focusout', cellUnfocused);

function cellUnfocused() {
    console.log(this, "unfocused");
}
```

This will log the input element so now you can do functions as if it was a "not clicked on" listener.

Answer (score 0):

```
var clicked = false;

function check(){
 if (clicked === false) {
     // code
 };
}

target.addEventListener("click", function(){
    clicked = true;
    check()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several methods to check if a button hasn't been clicked:

Set a global variable:

```
var buttonClicked = false;

function clickButton() {
    buttonClicked = true;
}
```

Set a custom attribute:

```
<button clicked="false">Click me</button>

function clickButton() {
    if (this.getAttribute('clicked') == 'false') {
        this.setAttribute('clicked', 'true');
    }
}

if (button.getAttribute('clicked') === 'true') {
   // your code
}
```

Comment: Custom attributes are bad, use `data-XXX` attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Below how it looks like in vanilla `JavaScript`.
You can set global variable to check a state.

```js
var btnClicked = false;
document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function() {
  btnClicked = true;
  document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "Clicked = true";
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">
Click
</button>
<p id="text">
  Clicked = false
</p>
```

Then you can verify the state as you mentioned

```
if (btnClicked === false) {
}
```

Comment: Put your code here, not jsfiddle, using a Stack Snippet.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript undefined properties on objects are falsey. So you can just write something like:

```js
button = {}; //obviously assign to your button.
if (!button.clicked) {
  //do stuff like:
  console.log(!button.clicked);
}
```

It might not be best practice, but it's short and convenient.